# C/C++ within Ruby code?

Tags: c++, c, ruby, interop, embed

C/C++ would be good option to write some of the performance critical aspects of a Ruby Application. I know this is possible.

I would like to know how to add C/C++ code into Ruby code; any other language for that matter.

Are there any practical applications of this which you noticed in open source projects or else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Besides "Extending Ruby", here are two other resources:

- [README.EXT (extension.rdoc)](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/doc/extension.rdoc) - shows you more about how to build C extensions. A good compliment to "Extending Ruby"
- [Ruby Inline](http://www.zenspider.com/ZSS/Products/RubyInline/) - This is a library that tries to make it easier to build C extensions by having you call methods in ruby to compile C code.

Answer (score 5):

Look in the "Extending Ruby" section of the Pickaxe book:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html

Answer (score 4):

you should have a look at [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) - it allows you to create ruby extensions in C/C++.

Answer (score 2):

We use [ffi](http://rubygems.org/gems/ffi) in one of our projects.

> Ruby-FFI is a ruby extension for
>   programmatically loading dynamic
>   libraries, binding functions within
>   them, and calling those functions from
>   Ruby code. Moreover, a Ruby-FFI
>   extension works without changes on
>   Ruby and JRuby.

It works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Compile your high performance code into a system service/executable, and call it from inside Ruby...?

Comment: Sure, system service would be one of the ways. It would be all right for some situations. And probably clumsy to run a system service for small pieces of c++ code in a big algo written in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to read up on [Extending Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ext_ruby.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is probably one of the first things to study.