# How to use Ruby in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, ruby, shared-libraries

I have some experience in C/C++ but I am new to Ruby. So today I got a task from my teacher to use some other languages to create a shared library (in my case, .so) that I will use in my C++ program. I wanted to try Ruby for a long time, but now when I compiled, installed and played with it a bit, I have no idea what's next.
I googled alot, but all I can find (SWIG, Rice) is related to using C/C++ in Ruby, not Ruby in C/C++. Is it possible? Am I wrong with SWIG and Rice and I actually CAN use them vice-versa (ruby for c, c for ruby)? If it is so, can you please attach any guides about that?

Comment: well you can use mruby http://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2012/04/25/getting-started-with-mruby/ but im not suggesting use Ruby to create a shared library as it is not a compiled language.

Comment: Asking for external resources is off topic. However, you could take a look at this which includes a short section towards the end on embedding Ruby in a C application (yes, it is possible, and the interface definitions are pretty much the same whichever you embed in the other): http://media.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/ext_ruby.pdf

Comment: What are the conditions/limitations for running Ruby from within C/C++ ? The simplest is to `execve` a ruby interpreter if not forbidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ruby is an interpreted language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29), and I've [never seen it compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5902504/1454158). What I know is that you can [drop into C/C++ from within ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250056/c-c-within-ruby-code). It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. You might be looking for something that doesn't exist or make sense?

In Ruby, libraries are called [gems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems), which are a collection of [classes](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Class.html) [modules](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html) and other related files.

If you're looking for information about similarities between ruby and C/C++ this might be a good starting place. https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/to-ruby-from-c-and-cpp/

Other than that, please do some more research and refine your question.

Comment: i now see that you can use only compiled languages for making libraries. thanks

Comment: you can delete the question as off topic